# How does WPF store the language dictionaries?

Tags: .net, wpf, com, spell-checking

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck(v=vs.110).aspx

There are 4 languages supported. How does it store the dictionaries? Is it a (signed) resource file? An access database?

Mostly, I need to get access to the list of the words in the dictionary, so programmatic access to that word list would be great, but I'm also curious about the implementation.

I have traced it down to the [SpellerInterop](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/SpellerInterop.cs), but then if I understand my `COM` (And I'm not trying to say I do, it calls to a DLL with a guid (`d385fdad-d394-4812-9cec-c6575c0b2b38`). I don't know how to dig into that guid. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you found an answer? I'm looking for an answer too.

Comment: @MarcusDock That was 2 1/2 years ago, and I left the company. I don't recall what we did for a solution, but I don't think we found the answer. I pass the torch to you :D