# How do I dig into a COM object?

Tags: .net, com

I'm digging through the .NET source, and I found an interop class to a COM object. If I have the guid, how do I go about finding the DLL and class in question (and for that matter, how does .NET load the DLL based on the guid)?

Is it in the GAC somewhere?

Comment: Very broad question, this is much easier to answer with explicit hints on where to look in the registry and disk if you describe what you found.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, it is a broad question. Mostly because I don't know what to ask. I'm working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615152/how-does-wpf-store-the-language-dictionaries , but no one has answered, so I'm digging in myself, and learning a little about COM along the way.

Comment: That is not going to get you very far, it uses an undocumented api.  You misread the Guid, the CLSID is 333E6924-4353-4934-A7BE-5FB5BDDDB2D6.  That takes you to c:\windows\system32\NaturalLanguage6.dll.  Written in C++, you can't decompile it.  It does have type library embedded, you can take a peek at it by running OleView.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.  Use its File > View Typelib menu command.  But that's as far as you'll get.

Comment: @HansPassant What about disassembly? That class has to be getting it's word list from somewhere.

Comment: Anything is possible, a rough estimate is about 1 day per kilobyte of machine code when you get started.  It is a one megabyte file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM dlls are not placed into the GAC (which is for .NET assemblies only - hence the name *Global Assembly Cache*).

If you know the guid of a COM component and want to know the path to the actual binary you can figure that out using in the Registry.

Start `regedit.exe`, navigate to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<guid value>\InprocServer32
```

and check the default value of the key. Alternatively, for command line lovers, use the `reg.exe` tool:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0000002F-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
```

> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{0000002F-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\InprocServer32
>    (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll
>    ThreadingModel    REG_SZ    Both
> ```

Comment: Ah, yes, not the GAC.